# Python os.remove - No such file in directory

Tags: python, operating-system

I have below code to remove a file in one of my local folders. I have taken the code from other user posts.

However, it does not seem to be working for me. Below is my code

python

```
import os

def deletefile():
    filePath = "‎⁨‎⁨/Users/Jose/Documents"
    os.remove(os.path.join(filePath, "tweets.db"))
    print("Ok while deleting file ", filePath)

deletefile()
```

And below is the error that I am getting. What am I doing wrong? Why Python is placing "\u200e\u2068\u200e\u2068/" in front of my path?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 17, in <module>
    deletefile()
  File "tests.py", line 11, in deletefile
    os.remove(os.path.join(filePath, "tweets.db"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\u200e\u2068\u200e\u2068/Users/Jose/Documents/tweets.db'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-type your variable `filePath = /Users/Jose/Documents` manually

There are some invisible `'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK' (u200e)` and `'FIRST STRONG ISOLATE' (u2068)` characters in the string

Comment: That was the problem. I have entered the path manually and it is working now.

Comment: How would you deal with this if you can't retype the path? I am getting a list of files with glob and having this same problem.

Comment: Why can you not retype the path? Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a unicode left-to-right mark in your `filePath` line. It won't show up in most text editors (I can see it in vim). You should re-type that line manually.