# Pytorch datasets.ImageFolder flag FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\u2068/

Tags: python, pytorch

Trying to load data from the local directory in Pytorch using dataset.ImageLoader but getting FileNotFoundError...

```py
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

data_dir = '⁨/Users/Desktop/Udacity/AI for Trading/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/intro-to-pytorch/data⁩/Cat_Dog_data⁩/⁨train⁩'


transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
                                transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                transforms.ToTensor()])

dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root=data_dir, transform=transform)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\u2068**/Users/Desktop/Udacity/AI for Trading/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/intro-to-pytorch/data\u2069/Cat_Dog_data\u2069/\u2068train\u2069'

**Answer:** Retyping the Image Dir Path manually instead of copy-pasting solved the problem.

Comment: solved, to close

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to pytorch or dataset library, it seems getting reported by python's OS library..

I tried loading the simple path like

```
import os

data_dir = '/Users'
os.chdir(data_dir)
```

Even above code failed, post researching it seems, the error is because of the below reasons:

There are some invisible 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK' (u200e) and 'FIRST STRONG ISOLATE' (u2068) characters in the st

**And retyping the path manually (instead of copy-pasting) solved the problem**

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187698/python-os-remove-no-such-file-in-directory) helped me fix the problem, I still thought to post it again, as a problem in the context of pytorch was not reported and hopefully, this help folks connects the dots.